# IDEA hangs on remote debugging port

Tags: debugging, tomcat, jvm, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I'm remote debugging a tomcat at another server. Tomcat is started with the following parameters (among others):

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5556
```

After tomcat startup, the remote port shows up:

```
itadmin@srv-app02:~$ netstat -tulpen | grep java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5556            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       2005708     30667/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      1000       2006491     30667/java 
....
```

After connecting the IDEA debugger seems to hang. I get no message about the successful connection to the remote JVM.

At the moment I have no idea what causes the problem. Any hints?

Comment: Verify you don't have any method breakpoints, see http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-23.

Comment: Holy sh%^. I had no method breakpoints but few line breakpoints. I removed these and the debugger connects smoothly.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - would you mind to move your comment into a regular answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The common case for such problem is method breakpoints, it's [mentioned in the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-23).

You say it was caused by line breakpoints which is weird, never seen such problem before, but in theory source code in the IDE and compiled classes on the server could be out of sync and the IDE could send target VM the instruction to stop on the breakpoint in the wrong place which the VM did and hung.

Comment: Have to admit that the problem is much more weird. When I disable all breakpoints, the debugger connects to the remote JVM. But when I enable a breakpoint and run the application the breakpoint will not be hit. From the log I see that the code has been executed. Have still no idea.

Comment: Verify that sources/classes are in sync, try to rebuild the project with debug info enabled.

Comment: Sources are in sync. Same strange behavior. Rebuild (and necessarily redeploy) is unfortunately not an option. At the moment I blame IDEA for this problem. I tried to remote debug the tomcat with NetBeans (with the same sources folder attached) and everything works fine.

Comment: You can try to remove the project's `.idea/workspace.xml` file when IDEA is not running, then open the project again. It will reset the breakpoints and other project specific settings. Also try running the remote process with the following options instead of `-Xdebug` (which is obsolete): `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=<debug-port>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The combination of using `-agentlib...` instead of `-Xdebug...` and resetting the workspace by deleting `workspace.xml` fixed this issue.

Comment: @CrazyCoder,  may I ask you to have a look at a remote-debugging related question here : tinyurl.com/ovglq92 ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem here and it let me crazy for a while. I found out that a recent installed plugin **La Clojure** messed up with my Tomcat environment. I know you solve this in a different way, but I am answering here because it can be useful for others.

Try to uninstall recent installed plugins, or reinstalling the IntelliJ IDEA.